# Output file names with spaces to file without quotes in batch

Tags: batch-file, ffmpeg

So, I wrote a script as a batch file that uses FFmpeg to "concat" several video files on my hard drive.
The script is as follows.

```
@echo off
title Printing video info...
(for %%i in (
"%USERPROFILE%"/Dropbox/Video1.MKV
"%USERPROFILE%"/Dropbox/Video2.MKV
S:/Exports/Video3.MKV
../../video/Video4.mkv
) do ( if exist "%%i" echo file '%%i' )) > "%~n0.txt"
type "%~n0.txt"
title Copying to compiled video...
"C:\Program Files\ffmpeg\bin\ffmpeg.exe" -hide_banner -f concat^
                  -safe 0 -y -i "%~n0.txt" -c copy "%~n0.mkv"
```

The problem here is the username on the computer has a space in the name, so the script doesn't work. If I put the quotes with `%USERPROFILE%`, then the file is detected by the batch script, but the batch script also puts the quotes into the output TXT file, which causes FFmpeg to fail when it hits that file.

The contents of the text file the script outputs to should be:

```
file 'C:\Users\Name/Dropbox/Video1.MKV'
file 'C:\Users\Name/Dropbox/Video2.MKV'
file 'S:/Exports/Video3.MKV'
file '../../video/Video4.mkv'
```

Comment: "without quotes in bash".. you mean BATCH??  You should edit your question.

Comment: Fixed it, I get mixed up with these names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Quote all the file path](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-esc.html) and apply the [`~` modifier properly](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html) to `%%i` as follows:

```
(for %%i in (
    "%USERPROFILE%/Dropbox/Video1.MKV"
    "%USERPROFILE%/Dropbox/Video2.MKV"
    S:/Exports/Video3.MKV
    ../../video/Video4.mkv
) do ( if exist "%%~i" echo file '%%~i' )) > "%~n0.txt"
```